# Linked Server - LDAP - Msg 7321

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, ldap, openquery

Below is an abbreviated query I am trying to execute against LDAP using a linked server:

select * from openquery(ADSI,'')

The query runs fine, except when I change the "Domain controller: LDAP server signing requirements" security setting to "Require signing" on the LDAP server.  When I do that, I get the following error:

Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 1

An error occurred while preparing the query "" for execution against OLE DB provider "ADSDSOObject" for linked server "ADSI".

The linked server ADSI is created using a domain account.  Also, we would prefer not to use OPENROWSET if we can help it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using TLS/SSL?

If you "Require signing", then the LDAP data-signing option must be negotiated unless Transport Layer Security/Secure Socket Layer (TLS/SSL) is being used.

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823659 for more information.

May be unrelated, but I noticed there is no explicit 
'SELECT * FROM "LDAP://DC=MyDC,DC=MyOtherDC"' 
in the query portion of OPENQUERY

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and the solution was to set up a kerberos trust between the SQL server and the domain controller, so it would allow user credentials to be passed-through (aka double-hop).

I used "Active Directory Users & Machines" to find my SQL server and add a SPN allowing credentials to be passed from the SQL server to the LDAP/DC server.

In SQL server, my query looked a little different from the ones shown above:

```
select sAMAccountName as UserName, displayName, userAccountControl 
from OPENQUERY( ADSI, 'select sAMAccountName, displayName, userAccountControl 
     from ''LDAP://DomainServerName/DC=Domain01,DC=CompanyName01,DC=local'' 
     where objectClass = ''Person''')
```

I was able to construct the LDAP query using another tool called Softerra LDAP Administrator. You expand (depthwise) util you get to something like ServerName\DC=Corporation01\OU=Office01\CN=Users\CN=Department. If it has the list of users you want, check properties of that folder and your LDAP query will be in the title. It also does a decent job of showing which properties you can select or filter-on.