# Error to RUN select against Active Directory

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to run this query:

```
SELECT top 10 *
FROM openquery(ADSI, '       
    select  *    
    from ''LDAP://londcrwc02.adslocal.net:389/ dc=adslocal,dc=net''      
    where objectCategory = ''Person''      
    and objectClass = ''user''      
')
```

In two different servers, the first server can run the query perfect but the second one has this error:

> Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 163
> An error occurred while preparing the query "
> select  *
> from 'LDAP://londcrwc02.adslocal.net:389/ dc=adslocal,dc=net'
> where objectCategory = 'Person'
> " for execution against OLE DB provider "ADsDSOObject"
> for linked server "ADSI".

Comment: Is the Linked Server setup on the 2nd server?

Comment: Yes, of course the linked server in both servers created by SQL Admin,

Comment: Sounds like it is related to this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741528/linked-server-ldap-msg-7321